# Mysql find data that is between fields

Tags: mysql, range, between

I currently have data like this

```
            ID          range_1   range_2
|3V20.0303:3V20.0313|   |3V20.0303| |3V20.0313|

|3V20.0101:3V20.0108|   |3V20.0101| |3V20.0108|

|3V20.0305:3V20.0308|   |3V20.0305| |3V20.0308|

|3V20.0104:3V20.0104|   |3V20.0104| |3V20.0104|

|3V20.0501:3V20.0505|   |3V20.0501| |3V20.0505|
```

And i have problem to fine the data which is included in the range1 and range2.
it must be something like this

```
            ID          range_1   range_2
|3V20.0305:3V20.0308|   |3V20.0305| |3V20.0308|

|3V20.0104:3V20.0104|   |3V20.0104| |3V20.0104|

|3V20.0501:3V20.0505|   |3V20.0501| |3V20.0505|
```

Can any one help me?

I've been trying the code like this and it's all wrong.

```
SELECT id, range1, range2 
FROM tbl_test
WHERE range1 BETWEEN range1 AND range2 
   or range2 between range1 and range2
```

Comment: I don't think it is entirely clear what you are trying to achieve here, what is your range denoting in this instance? Deom the data it looks like your ID field is consistently range1:range2 for every entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly do a self join where the range_1 and range_2 are both between a rows range_1 and range2.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT a.*
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN SomeTable b
ON a.range_1 BETWEEN b.range_1 AND b.range_2
AND a.range_2 BETWEEN b.range_1 AND b.range_2
AND (a.range_1 != b.range_1
OR a.range_2 != b.range_2)
```